# Running SAVE AS using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, file-structure

I have a batch file that creates text files in multiple folders.

What I need it to do as well, is after creating that text file, save a copy of it as a .scr file

If I were to do with this without a batch file, I would open the text file, click SAVE AS and save the file with a .scr extension. I cannot figure out how to add this feature to my batch file however.

The original text file cannot be erased, so I can't just change the extension. I would have to copy it, then change the extension, or imitate the SAVE AS feature.

Help?

Comment: "If I were to do with this without a batch file" I would type: `copy file.txt file.scr` at the command prompt (the SAVE AS feature imitate COPY command, indeed)...

Answer (score 0):

I just used the ren *<> *<> command. It is extremely redundant because I end up making two text files that are identical and just changing one, but it gets the job done